# bootstrap: bitcoin glyphicon not appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug, glyphicons

I can't seem to show a bitcoin glyphicon:

Code: (in jade)

```
.input-group
                 input.form-control(type="text" placeholder="USD")
                 span.input-group-addon.glyphicon.glyphicon-usd

              .input-group
                 input.form-control(type="text" placeholder="BTC (Approx.)")
                 span.input-group-addon.glyphicon.glyphicon-bitcoin
```

The usd glyphicon appears no problem, but the bitcoin doesn't. Why that?

EDIT: Here's the HTML output as requested:

```
<input placeholder="BTC (Approx.)" class="form-control" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-bitcoin"></span>
```

Comment: What is the rendered HTML output?

Comment: @DavidG added as EDIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the latest version of Bootstrap. The Bitcoin glyphicon was only introduced in version 3.3.2.

Example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group">
  <input placeholder="BTC (Approx.)" class="form-control" type="text">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-bitcoin"></span>
</div>
```